# Using JS setTimeout in a bookmarklet

Tags: javascript, bookmarklet

I am trying to run some JS code in a bookmarklet in firefox. Here's some basic code to prove the point:

window.setTimeout( function() {alert('i ran');}, 1000 );

when I run code with setTimeout in it, I get the whole page replaced by the counter value that normally gets logged in the console.

Is there a way to catch this output and stop this happening?

Thanks!

Comment: can you show us the complete bookmarklet?

Comment: Hi, the location part of it looks like this: javascript:window.setTimeout(%20function()%20{alert('i%20ran');},%201000%20);

Answer (score 5):

Try the following:

```
javascript:(window.setTimeout(function() { alert('i ran'); }, 1000));void(0);
```

Answer (score 2):

When you use the `javascript:` protocol in an address bar (which is what all bookmarklets do), the browser does a `document.write` on whatever the return value is if it's truthy.

A `setTimeout` call always returns a number for the timer. To fix this you can either append a `void(0);` like epoch or as I like to do, wrap it in an [IIFE](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/):

```
(function() {
    window.setTimeout( function() {alert('i ran');}, 1000 );
})();
```